# How many beats does a quarter rest get in 3/4 time, and how do you count it?

Tags: rhythm, time-signatures, rests

How many beats does a quarter rest get in 3/4 time, and how do you count it?

I think it would be 1/2 beat. I also wanted to know what note this is and how many beats does it get in 3/4 time.

[image: A quarter rest]

Answer (score 2):

This is a quarter note rest, it is not a note. It gets one beat of rest in 3/4 time.

Here is some information on music notation:

https://method-behind-the-music.com/theory/notation/

Comment: ok thanks what about a dotted eighth note in 3/4 time

Comment: A dot after a note or rest increases its value by 1/2 so a dotted eight note is 1/8+1/16 or 3/16. The time signature is not relevant to note values, the total number value of notes in a measure just needs to match the value of the time signature. 3/4= 3 quarters or 6 eighth notes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Rests last exactly the same amount of time as their counterparts do when played. Imagine a silent note. Any note will have to last a certain time. Here, the rest is a crotchet rest, so will last as long as a crotchet. If we count 1-2-3, 1-2-3, at any regular speed, a crotchet lasts as long as one of those numbers, in 3/4 time.

Imagine that rest is on beat 2. Count 1-2-3, 1-2-3 but don't do anything on 2. You could play notes on 1 and 3, but have no sound on 2. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the beat is.

- If you're counting three quarter notes to the measure (the most common case) it's counted the same as a quarter note: one beat.
- If you're counting a whole measure as one beat (e.g. a Viennese waltz) then it's counted as a third of a beat.
- If you are counting a measure as sixth eighth notes (e.g. a piece marked 'adagio' or 'lento') then it's counted as two beats.